# Loop 3 times and add a new value each time to a new column in spark DF

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want create 3 rows for every row in  pysaprk DF. I wan to add a new column called loopVar=(val1,val2,val3). Three different values must be  added as  a value in each loop. Any idea how do I do it ?

Original:

```
    a   b   c
    1   2   3
    1   2   3

 Condition 1: loop = 1  and b is not null then loopvar =va1
 Condition 2: loop = 2  and b is not null then loopvar =va2
 Condition 3: loop = 3  and c is not null then loopvar =va3
```

Output :

```
    a   b   c  loopvar
    1   2   3  val1
    1   2   3  vall
    1   2   3  val2
    1   2   3  val2
    1   2   3  val3
    1   2   3  val3
```

Comment: do you want to create rows or add columns, or both? please provide input and expected output.

Comment: Have illustrated the existing and required output state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `crossJoin`:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([[1,2,3], [1,2,3]]).toDF('a','b','c')
df.show()
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|
|  1|  2|  3|
+---+---+---+

df2 = spark.createDataFrame([['val1'], ['val2'], ['val3']]).toDF('loopvar')
df2.show()
+-------+
|loopvar|
+-------+
|   val1|
|   val2|
|   val3|
+-------+

df3 = df.crossJoin(df2)
df3.show()
+---+---+---+-------+
|  a|  b|  c|loopvar|
+---+---+---+-------+
|  1|  2|  3|   val1|
|  1|  2|  3|   val2|
|  1|  2|  3|   val3|
|  1|  2|  3|   val1|
|  1|  2|  3|   val2|
|  1|  2|  3|   val3|
+---+---+---+-------+
```

Comment: Yes this is partially what I am looking for. But sorry I have added another condition. Sorry again to shift the target.

Comment: Actually you know what once the crossjoin is achieved then with .withColumn I can workout the conditions individually. But if you have more elegant solution that what I am thinking please do share.

Comment: @SuhasRajashekar that sounds reasonable